# Converting values in a dictionary to literal values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I know that you can be tricky and make a *known property* on a passed in dictionary into a literal value. For instance in the case of a dictionary with an "id", we could do this:

```
function idLiteral<
  T extends { id: I }, 
  I extends PropertyKey
>(o: T): T & { id: T["id"] } {
  return { ...o, id: o.id };
}
// usage
const test = idLiteral({id: "abc", name: "Bobs your uncle" });
```

and in this case `name` would be a *string* type but `id` would be assigned as the literal type `abc`. Of course in cases where the object is static we can just use the Typescript `as const` operator to convert the object to narrow literal types but what I'm wondering is if we can do this with non-static dictionaries passed through a function.

I attempted this with:

```
function literalValues<T extends object>(obj: T): T extends { [K in keyof T]: Readonly<infer V> }[keyof T] 
  ? { [K in keyof T]: Readonly<V> } 
  : never {
  return obj;
}
// usage
const narrow = literalValues({foo: 1, bar: true});
```

The hope was that the `narrow` variable would come out typed as `{ foo: 1; bar: true }`. Sadly this did not happen and out popped the widened types of `{ foo: number; bar: boolean }`.

I then turned my attention to seeing if maybe that first function -- `idLiteral` -- might be something that could be generalized so that I build up the object type by iterating over it. I came up with this:

```
export const literal = <T extends object, P extends keyof T>(obj: T) => (prop: P): T & { [P]: T[P] } => {
  return { ...obj, [prop]: obj[prop] };
};

const l = literal({ foo: 1, bar: true })("foo");
```

But this syntax fails because `P` can't be used as a key to the object.

Is this a doable thing in Typescript or am I just wasting time? Feels so close but at the same time so far off.

> [Playground Code](https://tsplay.dev/mA75vw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a pain point in TypeScript.  A while back I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) to request some simple way to annotate generic function signatures to infer types as if the caller had used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), without requiring the caller to actually do that.  That feature request is still open, but I don't know when or if it will be implemented.

For now, there are tricks to getting similar behavior, but they are mysterious to the  uninitiated.  One way which seems to work fairly consistently is to have two generic type parameters, one corresponding to the actual value being passed in (call it `T`), and the other corresponding to the part of that type you want to infer narrowly (call it `N`).  Then you [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to the relevant type, using `N` to represent the part with literals in it, and constrain `N` to a union containing `string`, `number`, and `boolean`.  Like this:

```
type Narrowable = 
  string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

function literalValues<N extends Narrowable, T extends Record<keyof T, N>>(
  obj: T
) {
  return obj;
};
```

When you call it, it behaves the way you want:

```
const narrow = literalValues({ foo: 1, bar: true });
/* const narrow: {
    foo: 1;
    bar: true;
} */
```

It's a little weird in that, while `T` is now inferred narrowly, `N` is not:

```
/* function literalValues<Narrowable, { foo: 1; bar: true; }> */
```

But you don't really care about `N`, so ‍♂️.

If you think there should be something less wonky, I agree.  You might want to go to microsoft/TypeScript#30680 and give it a  and/or describe your use case if you think it's particularly compelling.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgJwQewO5wEYBtoF4oDOwCAlgHYDmUAPlGQK4C2GECNUGyyOcZ7BIZt3bIMAKwgBjYO3pkAJhABm5CPPYA3ZCXW0GWLOwDeAXwDcAKCVzpJZHywlgrOFgBqr+hAIAeGFAgAD2cFAlhEFHRsCAAaKAAVAOCIUKgAJSlkBHkfAGsIEGQlBLiYAD4ygApRMQAuBIBKKCMLKCgECGB6BD4ay3MLC0l7IjoItCh8R2cEVw8sLwJKoyglLnqARjiMRHriLygTBssAegAqVZtgOwcnF3dPbz9xqJw4lbXkTbMOXah9iA-ExlKBnE6Dc5QYZkUZkF71FptNqfb6tJE7BB7BBefqg8GDIA)

Comment: your super powers are amazing ... thank god you're such a contributor to Stack Overflow.